# How to convert separators using regex in bash

Tags: bash, sed

How do I modify my bash file to achieve the expected result shown below ?

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1
var="$(<$filename)" | tr -d '\n'
sed -i 's/;/,/g' $var
```

Convert this input file

```
a,b;c^d"e}
f;g,h!;i8j-
```

To this output file

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
```

Comment: Maybe something like `sed -i 's/[^a-z]*/,/g'` and then `sed -i 's/^[^a-z]*//'`? This makes the assumption that a-z are the characters you care about and that sequences of anything else should be converted to a single comma.

Comment: Answering in comment since question is closed. Change script to :  #!/bin/bash; filename=$1; sed 'H;1h;$!d;x; s/([[:punct:]]|[0-9])/,/g;s/\n//g;s/[,]{2,}//g;s/(^,|,$)//g;s/([a-z])([a-z])/\1,\2/g' -E -i $filename

Comment: Which characters do you want to replace with a comma and which ones do you want to remove?

Answer (score 1):

> How to convert separators using regex in bash

You would, well, literally, do exactly that - convert any of the separators using regex. This consists of steps:

- most importantly, figure out the exact definition of what consists of a "separator"
- writing a regex for it
- writing an algorithm for it
- running and testing the code

For example, assuming a separator is a sequence of of any of `\n,;^"}!8-` characters, you could do:

```
sed -zi 's/[,;^"}!8-]\+/,/g; s/,$/\n/' input_file
```

Or similar with first `tr '\n' ,` for example when `-z` is not available with your sed, and then pass the result of `tr` to sed. The second regex adds a trailing newline on the output instead of a trailing `,`.

Additionally, in your code:

- `var` is unset on `sed` line. Parts of `|` pipeline are running in a subshell.
- `var=$(<$filename)` contains the *contents* of the file, whereas `sed` wants a filename as argument, not file contents.
- `var=.... | ...` is pipeing the result of assignment to `tr`. The output of assignment is empty, so that line produces nothing, and its output is unused.

Remember to check bash scripts with shellcheck.

Comment: Perhaps note that `-z` and `-i` are not standard options for `sed`, and the semantics of `\n` also differ between versions.

Answer (score 0):

For a *somewhat* portable solution, maybe try

```
tr -cs A-Za-z , <input_file | sed '$s/,$/\n/' >output_file
```

The use of `\n` to force a final newline is still not entirely reliable; there are some `sed` versions which interpret the sequence as a literal `n`.

You'd move `output_file` back on top of `input_file` after this command if you want to replace the original.